# E-Mail sending with Send-MailMessage works, but not with SmtpClient

Tags: powershell, smtp, system.net.mail

The following Powershell script works on my Windows Server 2012:

```
send-mailmessage -from "from@domain.com" -to "to@domain.com" -Subject "test" -Body "test body" -smtpserver myhostip -credential "mydomain\myuser"
```

When I execute it, a window appears that prompts for the password of the specified user. I enter the password and the e-mail is sent.

**However,** the following script does not work:

```
$smtp = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient("myhostip")
$smtp.usedefaultcredentials = $false
$smtp.enablessl = $false
$smtp.credentials = new-object net.networkcredential("myuser", "mypassword", "mydomain")
$smtp.send("from@domain.com", "to@domain.com", "test", "test body")
```

It results in the error message

```
Exception calling "Send" with "4" argument(s): "Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: 5.7.1
<to@domain.com>... Relaying denied. IP name lookup failed [ip-address-of-my-web-server]"
```

What's the difference? How can I get the second script to work?

Comment: did you try turning it all into variables and plugging the variables into the first script, wouldn't that work?

Comment: Duh!! The `from` address had one `-` character missing in the `SmtpClient` version of the script. THANK YOU!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you try turning it all into variables and plugging the variables into the first script, wouldn't that work?